# Doesn't load picture from valid URL

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]]];
```

I use the code above and then check

```
if (image)
    return image;
else
{
    NSLog(@"no image on URL");
    return nil;
}
```

But sometimes (very very seldom) I don't get an image from a valid url. The url is valid 100%.

Usually it takes nearly one second to load a picture, but when it can't load a picture the process takes much more time (20-200 seconds).
And then i get "no image on URL".

Is there a better way to get a picture from URL?
I'd rather get "no image on URL" in one second then waiting so long.

P.S. srry for my poor english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very rare that you want to use `dataWithContentsOfURL:`. It's a blocking call so requires a background thread. It's also inflexible and doesn't provide good error returns (which is the problem you're encountering).

See the [URL Loading System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html). Generally you'll want to configure an asynchronous `NSURLConnection` for this kind of work. If you're doing a lot of network operations, you may want to consider a framework like [MKNetworkKit](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKNetworkKit) or [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) which handle a lot of the complexities for you.